# Neo4j create node with conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, knowledge-graph

[image]

As you see in image, A is connected to B,C,F,G. When I query A like "Match (n:Label{Name:'Name'})", it's returning me B,C,F,G which is right, but I want "B" to be returned only if I query "A","D","E", like if the values of A,D,E are true.

Here D, E could be connected to something else, but only when the values of A,D and E are true B should be given. Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question as follows:

When I ask for neighbours of A, it should only return those neighbours that, if they themselves have other neighbours, all have `booleanProp = true`

This should get you there

```
MATCH path=(n:Label {name:'A'})-[:MYREL]->(m)

WHERE ALL (k IN [(m)--(l) | l.booleanProp] WHERE k)

RETURN path
```